# Using one controller or multiple controllers for a navigation page menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've noticed that some sites use a separate controller for each menu item on a navigation page.
Here is an example

if I have a menu on a page that looks like this

- messages
- profile
- inbox
- items purchased

when each item gets clicked it takes me to a new controller even though I still see the menu at the top of the page
ex.

```
www.somepage.com/messages
www.somepage.com/profile
www.somepage.com/items purchased
```

is there any advantage to having a different controller, like above, for each item in the menu. I'm trying to weigh the advantages of having multiple controllers here vs one controller with different actions like below and I'm kinda a newbie to MVC

is this better? 1 controller(menu) with multiple actions that show the different areas of the menu

```
www.somepage.com/menu/messages
www.somepage.com/menu/profile
www.somepage.com/menu/items purchased
```

one last thing to keep in mind is that I want to have sub menu items like
in menu/messages I want Incoming/Outgoing, so how would that look?

```
www.somepage.com/menu/messages/incoming 
www.somepage.com/menu/messages/outgoing
```

or would it be better to have

```
www.somepage.com/messages/incoming
www.somepage.com/messages/outgoing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all kinda preference, but I think the standard would be different controllers.

Different controllers gives you the default seperation, and if you're using the default routes it works nicely if you want to add on sub-menus.

```
www.somepage.com/profile -- standard profile page
www.somepage.com/profile/edit -- edit profile page with nice route
```

Of course you could do the same thing if you had them all in a menu controller, but then the routes get a bit messy, or you have to define how you want to do them in the route config manually.

Advantages to having them in one controller would be you only have one place to look/maintain when editing those specific actions (shrug).

Personally I like the different controllers for each mini 'section', mainly because it produces nice seperation, default routing is pretty decent and each controller can have different dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many controllers as you want, and you should definitely take advantage of that. You should always break up your code into the smallest possible logical units. That applies to every class, whether it be a controller, an entity, a view model, whatever. One of the golden rules of OOP is that a class should do one thing and do it well. You should never have one massive class that contains all kinds of totally unrelated functionality, and since a controller is just a class, it applies to controllers as well.

Your controller should only contain actions that deal with the one thing your controller is "about". Generally, that ends up being a particular entity, and is reflected in the controller's name. So for messages, you might have a `MessagesController` and all the actions dealing with messages would go there. But for profile, you should create a new controller, probably called `ProfileController` and put those actions there.

Comment: Ok, I'll use different controllers for each menu item. But what about the view? Each view would need to have html for the menu and the _Layout.cshtml(navigation) so they all look the same. Whatwould be the best thing to do here? Put the menu in a single shared view with the _Layout.cshtml in it and have them all use it? Or should I use partials or something? Kinda  newbie!

Comment: There's a slight performance hit for each partial view,  so for something relatively static like a site nav,  you should probably just put it in the layout directly. However,  either way is fine.